# how to execute kubectl from bash script

Tags: bash

Team,

I have a basic function and am getting error. basically, am trying to run kubectl via bash script. i even tried switching to its directory but still not woring.

```
node_cordon_info() {
    kgn='kubectl get node'
    if [ -z "$total_dgx_nodes_NotReady_state" ]; then
       echo "No dgx_nodes_Ready_state found"
    else
       cd /usr/bin/
       for dgx_node in "${total_dgx_nodes_Ready_state}"
         kubectl get node $dgx_node --no-headers -o json | jq '.metadata.name,.metadata.labels."ns.com/cordon-reason"' | paste - - | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1 https://jirasw.test.com/browse/$2' --
    fi
}
```

output

```
./dgx-node-status-local.sh: line 94: syntax error near unexpected token `kubectl'
```

```
which kubectl
/usr/bin/kubectl
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/bin/kubectl:/home/dtlu/deployments/:/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin:/usr/local/bin/kubectl:/home/dtlu/deployments/:/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin:/home/dtlu/deployments/:/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin:/home/dtlu/deployments/:/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin:/home/dtlu/deployments/:/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dtlu/backup/nvidia/nsv/maglev-validations:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad: did not close the for loop.

```
node_cordon_info() {
    kgn='kubectl get node'
    if [ -z "$total_dgx_nodes_NotReady_state" ]; then
       echo "No dgx_nodes_Ready_state found"
    else
       cd /usr/bin/
       for dgx_node in "${total_dgx_nodes_Ready_state}"; do
         kubectl get node $dgx_node --no-headers -o json | jq '.metadata.name,.metadata.labels."ns.com/cordon-reason"' | paste - - | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'echo $1 https://jirasw.test.com/browse/$2' --
       done
    fi
}
```